# ListView margins

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'm trying to show a list of images that have a specific height (less than the height of the screen) and I want the width to match the screen width.

When I put these in a Grid, I'm able to achieve the desired effect:

```
<Grid>
    <Image HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Source="Assets/someimage.jpg" ></Image>
</Grid>
```

But when I put them in a ListView, I see there's a margin on the left and right edge of the image. In other words, the image is not edge to edge.
Here's a (over)simplified version of my code:

```
<Grid>
    <ListView>
        <Image HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Source="Assets/someimage.jpg" ></Image>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

After reading other similar threads I tried using Styles to set the HorizontalAlignment property of ListviewItems to no avail. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you using binding (Itemsource) ?

Comment: Ultimately, I'd like to use binding but right now I'm not. I wanted to see if I'm able to achieve the desired look first, then move on to bigger and more complex things.

Comment: Not sure if it will help, but you can try to work with binding and set the ItemTemplate to Grid/Image and see if it solve your problem.  let me know if you need a code sample, and I will post one as an answer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First of all, when you add an Image on a listView, this image become a content of a ListViewItem, which you can remove the margins that this item applies automatically.

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Even doing this, you could still have a little margin, which is applied by the listview:

```
ListView BorderThickness="0"
         Padding="-1">
```

BorderThickness it is not enough to remove all margin, that's why we set the padding of the listView of -1, you could adjust this value to fit better on your Window.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks Bruno. This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Comment: Padding should be "0" not "-1", that value causes cropping...